# Need help with this shell script getting syntax error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wget

I would like this to search for a file and if it's over 250M then download it. If not do not download it.

```
echo "Name your file."
read
echo "Paste the url you wish to check below."
read url
if (( wget --spider $url | grep *M >= 250M ));
then wget -O $name $url
else echo "This is not what you are looking for."
fi
```

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: When asking about an error, you should always include the actual error you are talking about.

Comment: The errorS are there. Terdon meant "error message" of course. I make that clear not for @terdon naturally, but because OP has karma 1.

Answer (score 3):

There are various issues here. First, you are not actually saving the name as `$name`. You nead `read VARIABLE` to save the entered string as `$VARIABLE`. You also don't need the `echo` but more on that later.

Now, the syntax error you are getting is presumably this:

> line 6: ((: wget --spider http://example.com | grep *M >= 250M : syntax error in expression (error token is "spider http://example.com | grep *M >= 250M ")

That's because you're using a very wrong syntax. The `grep` will print the entire line, not only the number on megabytes. Therefore, you are actually attempting to check whether  a line like this:

```
Length: 272629760 (260M)
```

is more than `250M` and that makes no sense. In addition, the output of `wget --spider` is printed to standard error, not standard output so you need to redirect it to stdout in order to `grep` it:

```
wget --spider $url 2>&1 | grep ...
```

You also need to filter out everything but the number itself. One way of doing this is with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and `-P` for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) and `-o` to tell `grep` to only print the matching portion of the line:

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=M)'
```

In PCRE, `\d` means any digit and `+` means "one or more". The `(?=foo)` construct, the positive lookahead, will only match if the next characters are `foo`. So, the regex above will match one or more digits, followed by the letter `M`.

So, a working (and slightly improved) version of your script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Name your file: " name
read -p "Paste the url you wish to check: " url

if (( $(wget --spider $url 2>&1 | grep -oP '\d+(?=M)') > 250 ));
then
    wget -O $name $url
else
    echo "This is not what you are looking for."
fi
```

Or, for a more compact syntax that does the same thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Name your file: " name
read -p "Paste the url you wish to check: " url

(( $(wget --spider $url 2>&1 | grep -oP '\d+(?=M)') > 250 )) &&
    wget -O $name $url ||  echo "This is not what you are looking for."
```

Comment: Can you break down the perl string matching ? `\d+`  -> for one or more digits, etc...

Comment: @Cbhihe see updated answer. Apart from the `\d+`, the `(?=M)` is a positive lookahead. Read the link in my answer for more details.

Comment: Nice, concise and remarkably readable for even the simplest of Perl regexes. Thanks.  +1